# Print / Count all distinct pairs with equal sum in an unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-programming

Given an unsorted array,
for example : [6,4,12,10,22,54,32,42,21,11]

We need to find pairs with same sum.
Output:
(12,4) and (10,6) , SUM = 16 ; 
(42,22) and (54,10) , SUM = 64
etc ...

How do we proceed ? I have formed a 2D array calculating all pair sum combinations and did a search. It is not optimal way. Any better way to do it?

Follow up question is, print the index of the pair elements.

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'optimal'. Unless you expect to have millions of items in your array then I would suggest an exhaustive search would be simplest and clearest implementation. No need to improve performance if you don't have a performance problem.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem from a specific programming website? I would like to try my solution there. Are the elements in the array limited by some MAX.